# How to project a map with mapguide

Tags: web-mapping, mapguide

I am using MapGuide + Fusion for the basic Sheboygan-google [example](http://trac.osgeo.org/fusion/wiki/MapGuideCommercialOverlays). I need to project the Sheboygan.MapDefinition to SheboyganMercator.MapDefinition so I can correctly display the example over google maps. However the WKT in the example to project it is not validated by maestro. Also maestro does not support projecting to Pseudo-Mercator at this time.

How can I create the projection manually?

Comment: is mapguide + fusion automatically MG ent? Or is it MG OS with fusion control?

Comment: im not sure what Nate is using, but you can use Fusion with MGOS (and it's included). Fusion is built on top of numerous open source technologies and Fusion itself is open source.

Comment: @janechii I am using MGOS and Fusion - but for whatever reason I cannot get their basic Google and Sheboygan to work. Here's my [mailing list post](http://osgeo-org.1803224.n2.nabble.com/Can-t-get-fusion-to-work-using-Sheboygan-and-Google-Maps-td6580834.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to transform your map with MapGuide Studio or Maestro (Open-Source). But it's better to convert your layers with Autocad or ArcGis before the diffusion.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Can you recommend any free tools for converting layers?

Comment: maybe you can try qgis?

Comment: Maestro can project the layers and the map. It's Free. http://trac.osgeo.org/mapguide/wiki/maestro

Answer (score 0):

I know that previously MG projections were handled through mentor.
If you have Autocad map installed on the MG machine you could manage the projections with map and they would/could be used in MG.
It has been several years since I had a MG implentation so this all could have changed.
HTH